# Is it possible to add Term Meta Fields to a WooCommerce Attribute?

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic, term-meta

Is it possible to add Term Meta Fields to a WooCommerce Attribute? I know I can do this with regular categories, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do this with product attributes. (without a plugin)

Essentially I would like to add an image field, where the user can select an image from the gallery.

Thanks!

Comment: If you're talking about the "Black/Blue/Green" *term* as in [this image](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/attributes-configure-terms.png), then yes, you can add custom term meta to those terms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however I am not refecrrefing to colors. I would like a to associate a company logo with it's company name in an attribute called "Company".